# Python global declaration breaks the previous line

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, global

In the following program, I tried to assign oct with different values inside functions, and print it. In outer_function(), I assign oct = 10(line 10), which is private variable. But I add "global oct" at line 20. So I got a Syntaxwarning. While the strange thing is that I got output of line 19 as "oct in outer_function 2 = ABC". This line is before global declaration, I think it should be 10 assigned at line 10.

```
  1 #! /usr/bin/env python
  2 
  3 """
  4     Program:  function_scope.py
  5     Function:  Program for working through scope rules
  6 
  7 """
  8 
  9 def outer_function():
 10     oct = 10
 11     print "oct in outer_function 1 =", oct
 12     def inner_function():
 13         global oct
 14         oct = "ABC"
 15         print "oct in inner_function =", oct
 16 
 17 
 18     inner_function()
 19     print "oct in outer_function 2 =", oct
 20     global oct
 21     #del oct
 22 
 23 oct = 0
 24 print "oct in module before =", oct
 25 
 26 outer_function()
 27 
 28 print "oct in module after =", oct
 29 
 30 print "That's all folks!"
```

The result I got is :

```
In [245]: run ch05_03_function_scope.py
/home/sherlock/Desktop/IntroductionPython/Ch05_functions/ch05_03_function_scope.py:20: SyntaxWarning: name 'oct' is assigned to before global declaration
  global oct

oct in module before = 0
oct in outer_function 1 = 10
oct in inner_function = ABC
oct in outer_function 2 = ABC
oct in module after = ABC
That's all folks!
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if the `global` declaration of `oct` is before or after the assignment of a value to `oct`. Here `oct` will be a global name for the entire function. It cannot be a local variable for a while and later become a global one. You get the syntax warning because it is really good practice to have the `global` statement as the first thing in a function.

To check for yourself, add `print locals()` to your function:

```
def outer_function():
    oct = 10
    print locals()
```

Now, run your program. It will print:

{}

That means there are no locals. So `oct = 10` in line 10 did not create a
local variable because of `global oct` in line 20.

Now, comment out the `global` statement

```
print "oct in outer_function 2 =", oct
#global oct
```

Run your program again. It will print:

```
{'oct': 10}
```

Now you have a local variable that has been created in line 10.

Comment: Does this explain the behavior of your program to you?